# Change color text gantt chart google ( javascript ) without CSS

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization

How can i change the left text color without use or insert a css ? 
This code is the same as documentation. 
I know colors depend on resources. I would not change the colors of the activity bars but only the text associated with it.

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
      data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

      data.addRows([
        ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014', 'spring',
         new Date(2014, 2, 22), new Date(2014, 5, 20), null, 100, null],
        ['2014Summer', 'Summer 2014', 'summer',
         new Date(2014, 5, 21), new Date(2014, 8, 20), null, 100, null],
        ['2014Autumn', 'Autumn 2014', 'autumn',
         new Date(2014, 8, 21), new Date(2014, 11, 20), null, 100, null],
        ['2014Winter', 'Winter 2014', 'winter',
         new Date(2014, 11, 21), new Date(2015, 2, 21), null, 100, null],
        ['2015Spring', 'Spring 2015', 'spring',
         new Date(2015, 2, 22), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 50, null],
        ['2015Summer', 'Summer 2015', 'summer',
         new Date(2015, 5, 21), new Date(2015, 8, 20), null, 0, null],
        ['2015Autumn', 'Autumn 2015', 'autumn',
         new Date(2015, 8, 21), new Date(2015, 11, 20), null, 0, null],
        ['2015Winter', 'Winter 2015', 'winter',
         new Date(2015, 11, 21), new Date(2016, 2, 21), null, 0, null],
        ['Football', 'Football Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2014, 8, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 1), null, 100, null],
        ['Baseball', 'Baseball Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2015, 2, 31), new Date(2015, 9, 20), null, 14, null],
        ['Basketball', 'Basketball Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2014, 9, 28), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 86, null],
        ['Hockey', 'Hockey Season', 'sports',
         new Date(2014, 9, 8), new Date(2015, 5, 21), null, 89, null]
      ]);

      var options = {
        height: 400,
        gantt: {
          trackHeight: 30
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#configuration-options), use option --> `gantt.labelStyle`

```
gantt: {
  labelStyle: {
    color: '#ff0000',
    fontName: 'Arial',
    fontSize: 20
  }
}
```

although `fontName` & `fontSize` appear to work properly,
`color` does not...

notice the color doesn't change in the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['gantt']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([
    ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014', 'spring',
     new Date(2014, 2, 22), new Date(2014, 5, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Summer', 'Summer 2014', 'summer',
     new Date(2014, 5, 21), new Date(2014, 8, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Autumn', 'Autumn 2014', 'autumn',
     new Date(2014, 8, 21), new Date(2014, 11, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Winter', 'Winter 2014', 'winter',
     new Date(2014, 11, 21), new Date(2015, 2, 21), null, 100, null],
    ['2015Spring', 'Spring 2015', 'spring',
     new Date(2015, 2, 22), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 50, null],
    ['2015Summer', 'Summer 2015', 'summer',
     new Date(2015, 5, 21), new Date(2015, 8, 20), null, 0, null],
    ['2015Autumn', 'Autumn 2015', 'autumn',
     new Date(2015, 8, 21), new Date(2015, 11, 20), null, 0, null],
    ['2015Winter', 'Winter 2015', 'winter',
     new Date(2015, 11, 21), new Date(2016, 2, 21), null, 0, null],
    ['Football', 'Football Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 8, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 1), null, 100, null],
    ['Baseball', 'Baseball Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2015, 2, 31), new Date(2015, 9, 20), null, 14, null],
    ['Basketball', 'Basketball Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 9, 28), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 86, null],
    ['Hockey', 'Hockey Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 9, 8), new Date(2015, 5, 21), null, 89, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    gantt: {
      trackHeight: 30,
      labelStyle: {
        color: '#ff0000',
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 20
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

one option would be to change the color manually using script

first, need to identify the row labels from the bottom date labels
to do so, test the label value exists in the data table column for `'Task Name'`
use data table method --> `getFilteredRows`

the only problem with changing the color manually,
the chart will change the color back to its original,
anytime there is activity, such as hovering a row and / or row label

as such, need to use a `MutationObserver`, or something,
to keep the new color

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['gantt']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([
    ['2014Spring', 'Spring 2014', 'spring',
     new Date(2014, 2, 22), new Date(2014, 5, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Summer', 'Summer 2014', 'summer',
     new Date(2014, 5, 21), new Date(2014, 8, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Autumn', 'Autumn 2014', 'autumn',
     new Date(2014, 8, 21), new Date(2014, 11, 20), null, 100, null],
    ['2014Winter', 'Winter 2014', 'winter',
     new Date(2014, 11, 21), new Date(2015, 2, 21), null, 100, null],
    ['2015Spring', 'Spring 2015', 'spring',
     new Date(2015, 2, 22), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 50, null],
    ['2015Summer', 'Summer 2015', 'summer',
     new Date(2015, 5, 21), new Date(2015, 8, 20), null, 0, null],
    ['2015Autumn', 'Autumn 2015', 'autumn',
     new Date(2015, 8, 21), new Date(2015, 11, 20), null, 0, null],
    ['2015Winter', 'Winter 2015', 'winter',
     new Date(2015, 11, 21), new Date(2016, 2, 21), null, 0, null],
    ['Football', 'Football Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 8, 4), new Date(2015, 1, 1), null, 100, null],
    ['Baseball', 'Baseball Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2015, 2, 31), new Date(2015, 9, 20), null, 14, null],
    ['Basketball', 'Basketball Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 9, 28), new Date(2015, 5, 20), null, 86, null],
    ['Hockey', 'Hockey Season', 'sports',
     new Date(2014, 9, 8), new Date(2015, 5, 21), null, 89, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    gantt: {
      trackHeight: 30,
      labelStyle: {
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 20
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    $.each($('text'), function (index, label) {
      var rowIndex = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 1,
        value: $(label).text()
      }]);
      if (rowIndex.length > 0) {
        $(label).attr('fill', '#ff0000')
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know why but in my costumize "Cannot read property 'getFilteredRows' of undefined".
I just added the jquery library,

The only different between your solution is the array data container. Because i've to draw multiple charts.

var data = [];
//for loop with k index 
data[k] = new google.visualization.DataTable();
...
 var rowIndex = data[k].getFilteredRows([{
...
//end for