# Change color of Task Name in Google Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I am using Google Gantt chart to show the Project duration.

Now, the requirement is to show the entire Resource Name column in black color. Right now, they are showing in some random colors.

Below is my code related to Gantt chart option and customization functions:

```
var options = {
    height: 600,
    width: "100%",
    hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
            fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"]
        }
    },
    gantt: {
        criticalPathEnabled: false,
        labelStyle: {
            fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"],
            fontSize: 18,
            color: '#757575'
        }
    }
};
var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

// monitor activity, change bar color
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function(bar, index) {
        var barY;
        if (data.getValue(index, 4) > data.getValue(index, 3)) {
            bar.setAttribute('fill', '#b71c1c');
            barY = bar.getAttribute('d').split(' ')[2];
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(bar) {
                if (bar.getAttribute('y') === barY) {
                    bar.setAttribute('fill', '#f44336');
                }
            });
        }
        if (data.getValue(index, 4) < data.getValue(index, 3)) {
            bar.setAttribute('fill', '#FFFF00');
            barY = bar.getAttribute('d').split(' ')[2];
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(bar) {
                if (bar.getAttribute('y') === barY) {
                    bar.setAttribute('fill', '#FFFF00');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Now, I am using some conditional formatting to change the bar colors if the start date is less than the end date and vice-versa. Now, when i change the mutationobserver function to show the text color as black, the conditional formatting applied to bar color is getting removed.

Can anyone please suggest any changes to the above code so that I can get this done?

Comment: Found the solution in this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509044/change-color-text-gantt-chart-google-javascript-without-css]. The issue was due to stylesheets which was missing in my code.